# Play an encrypted mp3 file

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, encryption

I am currently trying to play a encrypted .mp3 file. The way I am currently using is:

`loading the encrypted file -> decrypting it -> save it to ISO -> play it with the backgroundaudioplayer`.

But this can take up to 10-15 seconds to start one .mp3 file. Is there any other way to do this faster ? 
For example is there a way to play from a stream and somehow decrypt it while playing ?

And is there actually the need for encrypting the files on the IsolatedStorage ? Since nobody should be able to touch them anyways ?!

Comment: I download WMA from website, store it in ISO storage and play it directly in AudioPlayer. I don't understand why you decript it. If you really need Wav items, it will take time. http://www.windowsphoneapplist.com/en/A_ring_tone-a80349.html

Comment: I use ProtectedData.protect to encrypt the .mp3 files, I am not using Wav items at any time.

Comment: Why? If you fully re-calculate the whole file, it will take time.

Comment: Because I am not allowed to save the files without encryption. Otherwise someone could just steal it.

Comment: Ok. Please see, MP3 encoder/decoder stream works without encription. If you have included, I think there is no way to do it fast because it is your own way and hardware nor software will be optimized to work that way. I recommend to find a solution for encrypting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well since its been so long I would recommend "Buffering" its really easy, have your decrypt stream give you a decent sized buffer from the first 20 or so seconds of the file, that should take a few seconds max much faster than waiting for the whole file, then just simply feed the backgroundplayer using the decrypted buffer whilst the rest is still decrypting.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing it that way. A good start point for everybody who needs to do this is the AudioStreamingAgent in wp7